# Excel with VBA: Refer to a sheet code name instead of the tab name

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

Because I will update the tab name every week, instead of the tab name, I want to use the VBA project sheet name(Sheet17) which won't change if I change the tab name.

My code is:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("update raw data")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 4 To LastRow
 Cells(i, 56).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet17.Range("O3:O300"),WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i,69).Value, Sheet17.Range("AB3:AB300"), 0))

     Next i

 End With
```

But it gave me this error:

`'1004' -Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class`

Comment: What sheet are the `Cells` on? Are you missing the `.` in front of each `Cells` call? Also, use `Long` instead of `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Sub test()
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Integer
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("update raw data")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 4 To LastRow
            .Cells(i, 56) = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet17.[O3:O300], WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, 69), Sheet17.[AB3:AB300], 0))
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```